# Firebase clousure is skipping itself for no reason

Tags: ios, firebase, swift3, firebase-realtime-database, swift4

I am trying to observe single event via firebase. The address is correct there is no mistake that I am aware of. Please help me out. It skips whole code that is posted below.

```
Database.database().reference().child("users").child(messagesWithId[indexPath.row]).child("metadata").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
        if let valueFromSnaps = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary{
            let allValues = valueFromSnaps.allValues
            cell.textLabel?.text = allValues[5] as! String

        }
```